# need to apply rule based algorithm for large corpus to find similar/relevant keywords present in array of elements

Tags: python, arrays, search, nlp, rules

Currently am working in NLP workspace respective to text data. I want to find out actual given keywords based domain dictionary with column through search based

```python
developer_position=['software engineer','florida','highest pay','startups']
analyst_position=['qa', 'testing','plsql']
data_science_position=['analytics lead','lead','python','R']
architect_position=['mongodb','technical architect','sql','java','kafka']
manager_position=['pmp certified','sixsigma', 'belt','delivery manager']

corpus=["software engineer positions are high demand in California",
   "qa average salary in USA is $120K-$150K",
   "Django & reactjs are minimum requirements for lead positions"]
```

**The output should predict which category position will fall into a particular row based on high probability keywords in each category**

Comment: Smells like Homework

Comment: @rioV8 could you help here if possible

Answer (score 0):

You could use [spaCy rule based matching](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) in Python; or in Javascript you can use [winkNLP custom entities](https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/custom-entities.html) or in Java use token regex of [coreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/).